# surface area of $y = e^{-x}, x \geq 1$, about $x$-axis

Tags: calculus

Find the surface area generated by rotating $y = e^{-x}, x \geq 1$ about the $x$-axis or state that the integral diverges.

I have the equation set up, but when I change the bounds, I end up with a lower bound of $\tan(e^{-1})$. Help!

Comment: What equation do you have set up?

Comment: $\tan(e^{-1})$ is just a number, by the way.  There's nothing "special" about it (in this context)--it's just like $5$, $2$, $\pi$, or $39.2184$.

Comment: I have:
2pi * integral from 1 to infinity of (e^-x)*(1+ (-e^-x)^2)^.5 dx set up. I substitute u for e^-x, and then do integration by parts. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start from the integral you mentioned in the comments, for it was correct:

$2\pi \int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-x}\sqrt{1+e^{-2x}}dx$

Make the substitution $u=e^{-x}$:

$=-2\pi \int_{u=1/e}^{0}\sqrt{1+u^{2}}du$

Now, substitute: $u=tan(\theta)$, giving $du=sec^{2}(\theta)$:

$=-2\pi \int_{\theta=tan^{-1}(1/e)}^{0}\sqrt{1+tan^{2}(\theta)}sec^{2}(\theta)$

This substitution is valid because the range of $tan(\theta)$ is all real numbers, so it can take on any value which u would have.

Now, using $tan^{2}(\theta)+1=sec^{2}(\theta)$ and canceling out the square root:

$=-2\pi \int_{tan^{-1}(1/e)}^{0}sec^{3}(\theta)d\theta$

This is a really famous integral so I won't do it by hand (it'll be on a google search in a second). It evaluates to:

$\int sec^{3}(\theta)d\theta=\frac{1}{2}sec(\theta)tan(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}ln|sec(\theta)+tan(\theta)|$

I then distribute the $2\pi$, and use the (-) to reverse the order of the bounds. Plugging in $tan^{-1}(1/e)$ gives terms with $sec(tan^{-1}(1/e))$. Using the same trig identity as before (solve for secant) shows that $sec(tan^{-1}(1/e))=\sqrt{(1/e)^{2}+1}$.

All in all, that gives:

$\frac{\pi}{e} \sqrt{(1/e)^{2}+1}+\frac{\pi}{e}ln|\sqrt{(1/e)^{2}+1}+1/e|$